# Posets of finite sequences are highly connected

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, co.combinatorics, posets, reference-request

I need the following result for an example in a paper I'm writing.  It's easy enough to prove, but I'd prefer to just give a reference.  Does anyone know one?

Fix $1 \leq k \leq n$.  Define $X_{n,k}$ to be the following poset.  The elements of $X_{n,k}$ are ordered sequences $\omega = (x_1,\ldots,x_m)$, where the $x_i$ are distinct elements of the $n$-element set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $m \geq k$.  The order relation is that $\omega_1 \leq \omega_2$ if $\omega_1$ is a subsequence of $\omega_2$.  The theorem then is that the geometric realization of $X_{n,k}$ is $(n-1-k)$-connected.

Comment: what's the geometric realization of a poset ? 

Comment: The set of chains is an abstract simplicial complex, so the geometric realization is just the realization of this complex.

Comment: ah ok. i was wondering if that is what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, an answer should appear in the paper "On lexicographically shellable posets" of Anders Bj\"orner and Michelle Wachs, in Transactions of the AMS 277, pp. 323-341.

Comment: Yes, this paper gives me exactly what I want.  Thanks!